# Why stopped when I install offline .NET Framwork 3.5 on win 8?

Tags: installation, .net-framework, windows-8, .net-3.5

I tried to install .NET Framework 3.5 on Windows 8. Write command in cmd area, that processed until 68% and then it stopped!  Why?

I typed:

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /All /Source:j:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess
```

I don't have any mistake in command and typed it like the microsoft MSDN. Can you help me?

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: what did you type?

Comment: @DaveRook   No.just hang the system when process arrived to 68%

Comment: @Sathya  I typed:  Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /All /Source:j:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess

Comment: Why are you trying to install .NET 3.5 when it supports .NET Framework 4.5 supports software targeted to 3.5

Comment: @Ramhound  Because I want to install software such as SQL SERVER 2008.

Comment: @Sathya.What do you do?you just edit my comment!!!I think it's not necessary to edit!if you can guide me OK else please don't retype my comments.Thanks.

Comment: @Hamid Maybe the source disc is bad?

Comment: @Hamid Slightly different command given here, I doubt it will make a difference...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is already installed on Windows 8 [apparently](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/29348-Netframework-3-5-SP1-offline-installer-for-W8).

You have to turn it on through "Windows Features"

Further options to install:

1. Fresh install Windows Developer Preview 8102 on a drive other than the boot drive.
2. When the setup asks you for Computer Name, User Name and password.. Enter into Sysprep Mode by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+F3
3. The Setup restarts and then enters into sysprep mode and logs on as administrator.
4. Connect to a network with active internet connection.
5. Now in the control panel, go to Programs and Features and then click on Turn Windows Features on or off.
6. Then choose Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 option and click on OK
7. This will start the process and asks for connecting to internet, click on yes and proceed.. it will download the files and then installs the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1, this will take a while and when it shows finish click on the finish button and close the windows expect the Sysprep dialog box shown.
8. Now in the Sysprep dialog box, choose OOBE and then generalize and then choose shutdown
9. Now after the shutdown, switch on and boot the system with a WinPE OS and capture the WIM image of the Windows Developer Preview Build 8102 installed drive.
10. Then copy the captured install.wim to your Windows Developer Preview Build 8102 ISO.
11. Now use my (unattended Setup) - Autounattend.xml script to auto install Netframework 3.5 SP1 each time when you install Windows Developer Preview Build 8102.

Comment: There is terrible behaviour around this on Windows 8. Whilst it is 'installed' by default, you still need to 'enable' it via installation media (web or installer files). There are certain cases where you need to uninstall specific updates before you can enable .NET 3.5. A complete mess and unreliable as I've encountered in Windows auto-provisioning scripts.